# Inverse problem in calculus of variations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, calculus-of-variations

I am interested in knowing which differential equations follow from a variational principle. I am reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_problem_for_Lagrangian_mechanics) and it provides the answer for ordinary differential equations. Is there a complete answer to this problem for general partial differential equations ? PDEs arise, for example, in Classical Field Theories of modern Physics and almost all that know originate from a variational principle. Please provide a summary of the answer (for the PDE case) and suggest books where I can learn about this subject of inverse problems in calculus of variations for ODE's and PDE's .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is also referred to as the Helmholtz equation.  The answer can be found using the variational (bi)-complex as discussed in

http://math.uni.lu/~michel/data/VARIATIONNAL%20BICOMPLEX.pdf

by Ian Anderson.